# Getting a net::ERR_ABORTED 404 from bundle

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I was hoping to get some help on an error I'm getting when I refresh the page. When I use Link component to head to `/store/:store_id` I don't get any problem. The Store component loads without a problem. But when I refresh the page, it disappears and within console I'm seeing this error

```
GET http://localhost:3000/store/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

All help and clarity is appreciated since I'm not sure why this is occurring.

UPDATE

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true
},
```

Comment: This is an issue of client vs. server side routing. There's a bunch of questions around this already, such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually

Comment: @Jayce444 Thank you for sharing that one. But the thing is, I saw that article a while ago and even though it did solve the problem, it seems to be failing when a route has an ID. Such as /store/:store_id. I have included my webpack devServer much similar to what is shown in the link.